# Branch.io links not working from within the app

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

We have branch sdk integrated in our android app. The following are the manifest details.

```
    <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="open"
                android:scheme="example" />
            <data
                android:host="bnc.lt"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The init code piece is as follows

```
Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
        branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked before showing up
                    Log.i("BranchConfigTest", "deep link data: " + referringParams.toString());

        }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
```

Following is the scenario which is not working.

1.If we click a branch link from within the app the referralParams in the above code piece is empty.If the links are from outside the app we are able to recieve the JSON String in referralParams in the correct way.

I am unable to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Alex's answer is the current, official response! Here's a non-supported unofficial workaround I just came using the deprecated 'shouldOverrideUrlLoading.' You can override the webview client to handle Branch specific links, and then use our HTTPS API to grab link data without resetting the session or opening/closing other apps. Once you have this data, render it.

*Getting link data within a webview within an app, workaround, emphasis on workaround*

```
private static final String BRANCH_DOMAIN = "yourdomain.app.link";
```

1. Create a webview client, set to webview object:

   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   if (url.contains(BRANCH_DOMAIN)) {
       // hit endpoint and parse data -> load data
   } else {
       view.loadUrl(url);
   }
   return true;
   }
2. How to hit endpoint to fill in above comment
   info -- https://github.com/BranchMetrics/branch-deep-linking-public-api#endpoint-3

example: curl "https://api.branch.io/v1/url?url=URL_ENCODED_URL_TO_FETCH&branch_key=..."

^ I cannot stress the emphasis on this being a non-supported method that I just came up with, so don't claw my eyes/rep out if it stops working or isn't ideal, just trying to suggest creative solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch here: **this is expected**. Our linking infrastructure is not designed to handle links opened from inside the same app, so unfortunately we can't support this particular implementation.

Comment: Hi Alex, Would you suggest any workarounds? We usually send support links for content to the users from within the app so that they can view it directly.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I will check with our Android engineering team to see if there are any new developments!

Comment: @AlexBauer Is it done yet or not ? I have the same problem: where I am on a webview and have a branch link visible on the webview(e.g : http://bnc.lt/xyz/xyz), when I click this link on the link itself it never redirects me to the corresponding page, rather it opens that branch link inside webview itself and the page says it can't be loaded. is there any mechanism to do this type of deep linking?

Comment: @GauravArora I haven't heard any new developments, but our Integration Engineering team might be able to help find a workaround: https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new

Comment: @AlexBauer Still facing same issue in 2019. Any updates on given scenario?

Comment: @ZaidPathan I believe this is still the expected behavior. Please feel free to contact the integrations team using the link above, so they can take a look at your specific implementation!

Answer (score 0):

Hope it can help others. What you can do to handle this is, if you are showing a link in textview, set the property `android:autoLink="web"` in layout design of textview and in kotlin class linkify the link like

```
val spannable = SpannableString(text//your link)
Linkify.addLinks(spannable, Linkify.WEB_URLS)
val linksPresent = Linkify.addLinks(spannable, Linkify.ALL)
Linkify.addLinks(spannable, 0)
```

set link movement method in your textview like

```
textView?.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod()
```

What it will do is, it make the app open link in the browser and from browser it will redirected to the app and so that branch will be able to catch that link. It is working for me.

Comment: @AlexBauer is it the correct way or not. It's worked for me.